# Store array into dynamic memory

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm passing an array to a constructor. Constructor has two parameters, pointer to int called data and int which is size of an array.

I'm allocation dynamic memory in constructor definition for this array and passing array pointer to this storage.

Last but one step is printing values in array through the pointer which is pointing to the first int value of this array.

The last step is freeing up memory in destructor delete [] data. In this step I got an error message: Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _CrtlsValidHeapPpinter(block).

I'm very new in C++ so I'm struggling what I did wrong in below program. Could you give me a hint, please?

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
private:
    int* data;
    int size;
public:
    // constructor and destructor
    Test(int* d, int s);
    ~Test();

    // few void methods
    void display_data(int size)
    {
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << data[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

 Test::Test(int* d, int s)
    : data{nullptr}, size(s)
{
    data = new int[s];
    data = d;
}

Test::~Test()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor is freeing memory" << std::endl;
    delete[] data;
}


int main()
{
    int data_array[5]{ 2,8,6,10,20 };
    Test* t1 = new Test(data_array, 5);

    t1->display_data(5);

    delete t1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the data here. Instead of :

```
data = new int[s];
data = d;
```

Which creates an array and then forgets about it. This would lead to the array being deleted multiple times!

Copy the content of your array:

```
std::copy(d, d+s, data);
```

Or even better, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

In yout `Test::Test` constructor you don't copy the array, you just copy the pointer. You need to use `std::copy` or `memcpy` (C-style) to copy the contents of `d` into `data`.

However, I would recommend to use STL containers (i.e., `std::vector`) instead of raw pointers. It will allow you to get rid of manual resource management (new/delete), which is error-prone and redundant.